# Invalid Razor @model generated code

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm encountering a bizarre issue when trying to add a @model directive in a Razor partial view.

When using the following line:

```
@model Tuple<int, Tuple<int, string, string>, int>
```

The following class declaration is generated:

```
public class _Page_views_forms_controls__filter_edit_cshtml : System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<Tuple<int {
```

Which then throws since it's syntactically invalid.

I've tried wrapping the type name in parenthesis, removing the spaces between the type parameters, changing the type parameters (removing nested Tuple), and changing it to `@inherits System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<...>` all with seemingly no effect.

I've never encountered anything like this before. What could be causing this behavior?

Comment: Simple fix - use a viewmodel class which wraps the data contained in `Tuple<int, Tuple<int, string, string>, int>`

Answer (score 3):

To expand on my comment, you can create a viewmodel class like so:

```
public class FooViewModel
{
    public Tuple<int, Tuple<int, string, string>, int> Data { get; set; }
}
```

Then in your controller, create a new instanced of that viewmodel and pass it to the view:

```
@model FooViewModel
@{
    var data = Model.Data;
}
```

This should help the Razor engine when compiling the view.

Comment: Is this strictly required? Am I unable to use a parameterized type as a model for some reason? My third Tuple field is actually a view model (not an int as shown here), with the first two being some context from a loop. I would like to not have to name that entity explicitly, hence the use of a Tuple.

Comment: It's not mandatory, but using a viewmodel is very good practice.

Comment: Agreed in general, but here specifically I do not think it is warranted. Regardless, do you have any thoughts as to what could be causing the behavior described? Even should I choose to go a different route I would want to understand the issue here.

Comment: I'll admit, this is unusual. I've not encountered this before either. I'm having trouble finding anything relevant on Google with similar symptoms to your own.

Comment: Indeed I have been unable to find anything related as well. It seems to be specific to Tuple, as Dictionary<int, Tuple<int, int>> works just fine, but Tuple<int, int> alone has the same issue. I'm thinking that perhaps it is the multiple generic overloads that are causing some confusion, but have no idea how to resolve it.